# wordpress previous_post_link not excluding category

Tags: wordpress

Im using previous_post_link and trying to exclude a custom taxonomy

This is the command line

```
previous_post_link( '%link', "", false, $area->term_id, 'area' );
```

For some reason i keep getting posts in the same category.

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Does your post belong to many categories? Try to assign only the excluded term to a post and see if it's working.

Comment: Only 1 category per post

Comment: If using a custom taxonomy, the `$in_same_term` should be also set to `true`: `previous_post_link( '%link', "", true, $area->term_id, 'area' );`.